# Phpactiverecord, updating NOW() for an object

Tags: php, mysql, phpactiverecord

I've been attempting to use phpactiverecord for a project.. and I'm struggling to see if I can actually pass a mysql function through any of its native updating methods.  I'm a little surprised I couldn't find an answer to this question anywhere else =P.

EDIT:
After a year of using the framework, a simple answer is to simply do:
`$object->date = 'now'`

Comment: so what have you tried a what errors did you see?

Comment: @dnagirl It's moreso that there's no obvious interface to say... $object->last_edited = 'NOW()', $object->save(); .. since in that case it's going to be put into a prepared statement.  I'm guessing I'll just have to create a separate query or just modify the fields in the database to be timestamps...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to call `NOW()` to update a timestamp field. There are several options.

- use an "updated_at" field: http://www.phpactiverecord.org/projects/main/wiki/Utilities#automatic-timestamps

  > Models with fields named created_at and updated_at will have those fields automatically updated upon model creation and model updates.
- Do some sort of update on a callback: http://www.phpactiverecord.org/projects/main/wiki/Callbacks
- Simply update it using a php function manually

  ```
  $obj->yourDateField = new \DateTime();
  ```

Comment: This ends up being close to my solution... since phpactiverecord uses php's date() function to get the date, I just set the value to that function.  It just worried me on whether php and mysql would always be using the same time server.

Answer (score 0):

While I could be off base, but I think that directly you don't pass sql into active record.  However my understanding of active record (from working with Yii's version of active record) is that active record is built upon a CDbConnection,  from the class CActiveRecord:

> /**
>        * @var CDbConnection the default database connection for all active record classes.
>        * By default, this is the 'db' application component.
>        * @see getDbConnection
>        */

in Yii to access this you can use the code:

```
$sql = 'select * from mytable';
$rows = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql)->queryAll();
```

if you aren't using Yii you'll have to lookup how to access the db object.